# I2C Raspberry Pi (master) to arduino (slave) Errno 121; Errno 5

Tags: python, parallel-processing, arduino, i2c

I am pretty new to asking in this forum. However, I have solved a lot of problems with the posts in this forum. So, thanks a lot to all of you for your tremendous help.

Now I have a problem I do not seem to be able to solve on my own. I am building an application that is able to read RFID cards and transfer them to an android app via BlueTooth. The setup:

1. The main board is an RPi zero 2w, connected via I2C to Arduino Nano via I2C (A4 and A5) and asks periodically for the data of two last cards read by an Arduino Nano.
2. 2 x Arduino Nano is connected to an RC522. The arduino reads and stores the last two cards it read.
3. Upon request from an android app via bluetooth, the data is transmitted to it.

The BlueTooth part and the android part are working fine. The I2C part has the following problem: if several cards are read one after another, at some point (after there are several perfect reads) the following errors are reported alternating:

[Errno 121] Remote I/O error

[Errno 5] Input/output error

Those errors are thrown while trying to execute bus.read_byte(breaderAddr)) and bus.read_byte(creaderAddr)). After one error occurs, only resetting the arduinos helps. Restarting the Pi Script does not help.

I can only guess that it happens because the loop() in arduino somehow disturbs the sendData(). I have tried to find a method to somehow prioritize the sendData() but did not find anything.

The arduino code:

```
/*
 * Typical pin layout used:
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 */

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x2b

 
#define RST_PIN   9     // SPI Reset Pin
#define SS_PIN    10    // SPI Slave Select Pin


String str ="";
String str2="";
String str3="hel2o";
int counter=0;
String lastUID="";
String preLastUID="";

unsigned long zeroTime=0;
unsigned long timeDiff=0;

int LastVsPreLast =1; //if 1: lastUID transmitted, if 2: preLastUID transmitted in sendData()
char data1[26];
char data2[26];


MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Instanz des MFRC522 erzeugen
 
void setup() {
  // Diese Funktion wird einmalig beim Start ausgeführt
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Serielle Kommunikation mit dem PC initialisieren
  SPI.begin();         // Initialisiere SPI Kommunikation
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();  // Initialisiere MFRC522 Lesemodul

      // initialize i2c as slave
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.onRequest(sendData);
    Serial.println("HALLO"); 
}
 
void loop() {
  // Diese Funktion wird in Endlosschleife ausgeführt
 str="";
  // Nur wenn eine Karte gefunden wird und gelesen werden konnte, wird der Inhalt von IF ausgeführt
  // PICC = proximity integrated circuit card
  if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {return;}
Serial.println("new card");

  if(mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()){    
   
    for (int i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
      // Abstand zwischen HEX-Zahlen und führende Null bei Byte < 16
      //Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
      
      str=str+mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
      
    }    
    int NewSize =25;
    int ActualSize =0;
    ActualSize = str.length();
    
    for (int i =ActualSize; i < NewSize; i++){
      str="0"+str;
    }

    //str3="länge: "+String(str.length());
    //Serial.println(str3);
    // Versetzt die gelesene Karte in einen Ruhemodus, um nach anderen Karten suchen zu können.
    //mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();

    if(lastUID!=str){
        preLastUID = lastUID;
        lastUID=str;  
      }

    
    lastUID.toCharArray(data1, 26);
    
    preLastUID.toCharArray(data2, 26);

    
    
    Serial.print("last UID: ");  
    Serial.println(lastUID);
    
    Serial.print("pre-last UID: ");  
    Serial.println(preLastUID);
       
    delay(1);
 
  }
  }

  


int index = 0;
// called for sending data(every byte/char once)
void sendData() {


  //Code to make sure that an interrupted sending to Pi is accounted for and the sending begins again at index 0. This in case the python3 scripts in Pi is interrupted while reading data
   if(index==0){
      zeroTime=millis();
      }
   timeDiff = (millis()-zeroTime);

  if(zeroTime !=0){
    if(timeDiff > 500){
      index=0;
    Serial.println(timeDiff);
    }
    }

    
  
  
    //Code to handle the alternating sending of two variables
    if(LastVsPreLast==1){
      if(index==0){
        Serial.print("beginning transmission to pi: " );
        Serial.println(data1);
      } 
      Wire.write(data1[index]);
    }
    else {
      if(index==0){
        Serial.print("beginning transmission to pi: " );
        Serial.println(data2);
      }
      Wire.write(data2[index]);
    }

           
    index = index+1;    
    
    //Code to reset index after last char/byte was sent. Also to alternate between two variable to be sent
    if (index >= sizeof(data1)-1) {
         index = 0;
         zeroTime=0;
         if(LastVsPreLast==1){LastVsPreLast=2;}else{LastVsPreLast=1;}
         Serial.print("LastVsPreLast: ");
         Serial.println(LastVsPreLast);
    }
}
```

The Pi code:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
import bluetooth
import smbus
import time
import os
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
print(sys.executable)
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
breaderAddr = 0x2a
creaderAddr = 0x2b
counter=0
globals()['breaderdata1'] = "Breader1: nothing"
globals()['breaderdata2'] = "Breader2: nothing"
globals()['creaderdata1'] ="Creader1: nothing"
globals()['creaderdata2'] ="Creader2: nothing"


print(sys.version)

@asyncio.coroutine
def ReadArduino():
        while True:
                read_breader()
                yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
                read_creader()
                yield from asyncio.sleep(2)

def loop_in_thread(loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(ReadArduino())

def read_breader():
        #Breader
        dataTemp1=""
        dataTemp2=""

        try:
                #Breader1
                for i in range(0, 25):
                        dataTemp1 += chr(bus.read_byte(breaderAddr))
                time.sleep(0.1)

                #Breader2
                for i in range(0, 25):
                        dataTemp2 += chr(bus.read_byte(breaderAddr))              

        except OSError as error :
                print(error) 
                
        globals()['breaderdata1'] = "Breader1:" + dataTemp1
        globals()['breaderdata2'] = "Breader2:" + dataTemp2
        print(breaderdata1)
        print(breaderdata2)

def read_creader():
        #Creader
        dataTemp1=""
        dataTemp2=""
        try:
                #Creader1
                for i in range(0, 25):
                        dataTemp1 += chr(bus.read_byte(creaderAddr))
                time.sleep(0.1)
                #Creader2
                for i in range(0, 25):
                        dataTemp2 += chr(bus.read_byte(creaderAddr))
        except OSError as error :
                print(error) 
                
        globals()['creaderdata1'] = "Creader1:" + dataTemp1
        print(creaderdata1)
        globals()['creaderdata2'] = "Creader2:" + dataTemp2
        print(creaderdata2)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

t=threading.Thread(target=loop_in_thread, args=(loop,))
t.start()
 

#time.sleep(5)

host = ""

port = 1        # Raspberry Pi uses port 1 for Bluetooth Communication
# Creaitng Socket Bluetooth RFCOMM communication
server = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
print('Bluetooth Socket Created')
try:
        server.bind((host, port))
        print("Bluetooth Binding Completed")
except:
        print("Bluetooth Binding Failed")
server.listen(1) # One connection at a time
# Server accepts the clients request and assigns a mac address.
client, address = server.accept()
print("Connected To", address)
print("Client:", client)

try:
        while True:
                # Receivng the data.
                data = client.recv(2048) # 1024 is the buffer size.
                print(data.decode("utf-8"))
                dataString = data.decode("utf-8") 

                if dataString == "1":
                        print("light onn");
                        send_data = "Light On "
                elif dataString == "TransmitMeasurements":
                        print("beginning transmitting measurements");
                        send_data = "Breader1:"+ str(globals()['breaderdata1'])
                        #asyncio.create_task(ReadArduino())
                else:
                        send_data = "received: " + dataString
                # Sending the data.
                client.send(send_data)

except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        # Making all the output pins LOW
        # GPIO.cleanup()
        # Closing the client and server connection

        print("shutting down BT")
        
        client.close()
        server.close()
        print("restarting")
        os.system("python3 /home/pi/BTtest.py")
```

[Here is the wiring schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmJlu.png)

Any hint is very much appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help.

Cheers
Andy

Comment: Care to post a connection schematic? (I’m lost in the explanation of how many participants and how they are connected with each other)

Comment: Hi 0andriy, thanks a lot for your comment. I added the schematics in the original question.